# How to draw a rounded border pie chart

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build a pie chart that will look like this:

[image]

I've tried both `Flutter_Charts` and `FL_Chart`, but it seems none of them support a rounded corner and spaced items in the pie chart.

Does anyone know what is the best way to achieve this design as a pie chart?

Thank you!

Comment: Using dart:ui you can draw circle and draw arc maybe start by looking there.

Comment: Use clipper with container, then use border for circle line..

Comment: You can fork the source of this package in github. And enter changes in it and push and then use it .

Comment: see this link about pie chart with a round angle: https://medium.com/flutteropen/canvas-tutorial-04-how-to-draw-a-pie-chart-and-with-a-round-angle-in-the-flutter-8a22126704f4

Comment: https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/circular-charts/chart-types/doughnut/rounded-corners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar version to your chart can easily be achieved with the [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget.

Here is the resulting chart
[image: Resulting chart]

To achieve this you will just need a very rudimentary [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) that draws arcs across its canvas.
The rounding effect is achieved through the [strokeCap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/strokeCap.html) attribute of the [Paint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint-class.html) that is used to draw the stroke. Sadly [StrokeCap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/StrokeCap.html) only supports
round and square stroke endings.
A rounded rectangle effect like the one in your screenshot cannot be achieved through this.
Colors are achieved by using a separate [Paint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint-class.html) for each stroke.

```dart
// this is used to pass data about chart values to the widget
class PieChartData {
  const PieChartData(this.color, this.percent);

  final Color color;
  final double percent;
}

// our pie chart widget
class PieChart extends StatelessWidget {
  PieChart({
    required this.data,
    required this.radius,
    this.strokeWidth = 8,
    this.child,
    Key? key,
  })  : // make sure sum of data is never ovr 100 percent
        assert(data.fold<double>(0, (sum, data) => sum + data.percent) <= 100),
        super(key: key);

  final List<PieChartData> data;
  // radius of chart
  final double radius;
  // width of stroke
  final double strokeWidth;
  // optional child; can be used for text for example
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _Painter(strokeWidth, data),
      size: Size.square(radius),
      child: SizedBox.square(
        // calc diameter
        dimension: radius * 2,
        child: Center(
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// responsible for painting our chart
class _PainterData {
  const _PainterData(this.paint, this.radians);

  final Paint paint;
  final double radians;
}

class _Painter extends CustomPainter {
  _Painter(double strokeWidth, List<PieChartData> data) {
    // convert chart data to painter data
    dataList = data
        .map((e) => _PainterData(
              Paint()
                ..color = e.color
                ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
                ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round,
              // remove padding from stroke
              (e.percent - _padding) * _percentInRadians,
            ))
        .toList();
  }

  static const _percentInRadians = 0.062831853071796;
  // this is the gap between strokes in percent
  static const _padding = 4;
  static const _paddingInRadians = _percentInRadians * _padding;
  // 0 radians is to the right, but since we want to start from the top
  // we'll use -90 degrees in radians
  static const _startAngle = -1.570796 + _paddingInRadians / 2;

  late final List<_PainterData> dataList;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final rect = Offset.zero & size;
    // keep track of start angle for next stroke
    double startAngle = _startAngle;

    for (final data in dataList) {
      final path = Path()..addArc(rect, startAngle, data.radians);

      startAngle += data.radians + _paddingInRadians;

      canvas.drawPath(path, data.paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```

You can check out the [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=15e648ec2d41c5f957953e477938d03d) to experiment with a working example.

I am positive that the same chart you provided in that picture can be
achieved with a CustomPainter but that will be a lot more complex.